# Text rendering issue with <p> and <h2> in IE8 & IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I'm building a website but there seems to be a problem with the rendering of text in `<p>` and text in `<h2>`.

I have three columns in the footer but the center column renders its `<p>` text through the `<h2>` text.  The problem only appears in IE8 and IE9. All IE versions before IE8 + Firefox render just fine.

I already tried `position: relative`, margin and padding set to `0px` but nothing works.  I am using a `doctype`.

Below an image to show what happens:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls9aA.jpg]

Link to the full code on fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GWRfH/

Comment: Does your stylesheet declare any other styles that may apply to elements like the `h2` or the `p` tags?

Comment: Your CSS is useless without posting the corresponding HTML.

Comment: Extra code added, sorry.

Comment: @Moses no other code that use the elements h2 or the p tag is in my css file

Comment: Can you recreate this bug on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @sg3s I can't recreate the bug in jsfiddle.

Comment: @thaunknown54 Provide us a HTML code, not a html code + php from your cms' template. Open the page, right click - view source - copy/paste. You can modify your phone number or personal data if it's that important (though it's weird, you publish your website in the internet but blurry personal data from that website here...).

Comment: @firian I'll provide the html code you asked for.

Comment: This is really good example of how does the xhtml websites shouldn't be coded. The example you provided doesn't include the bug you mentioned and showed on screenshot. As a sign of good will go to jsfiddle.net, make an example which will clearly present us a problem and paste the link here. If you're not going to do that, don't expect help. If you want help, provide us tools to help you.

Comment: @firian I didn't noticed the wrong code, allthough it is provided the correct way like you described. It's wrong probably because I forgot to add extra lines of CSS code. I provided them in this fiddle. Suddenly I can see the bug also in the fiddle (via IE9). Please be a bit more mild. I'm fairly new to HTML, 'though I understand your frustration. [Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GWRfH/)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see the bug you're talking about - even in IE9. I believe that there is no point in continuing the discussion further unless you provide us an uri to your website or working, fully "operational" demo on jsfiddle. Quick tip based on your screenshot - the "Contactgegevens" is an inline element (h2), the rest of the text is a block element - wrap your header with any block element, make it a block element or put it inside the <div> that contains the contact data, so that it would "reside" amongst other inline elements.

Comment: Your HTML is a mess. Opening and closing tags do not match. And you have a <a> element around the h2 in question. Older browsers don't like links around block level element. Try putting the link (a) inside the h2.

Comment: Thanks Firian and Gerben for your answers. I will take a look at it and surely look into your tips. I can't provide a demo and the fiddle which I posted is the exact html I use/the browser outputs. The mentioned <a> was a minor fix to a another strange bug. Which made the whole contact text a link. I declare hereby this question closed and therefor I don't need any more answers. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The problem has been fixed because I was using the wrong way of coding links `<a>`. I forgot numerous times to end the `<a>` tag with `</a>` instead I used `<a>` to end it. (I know this was pretty stupid of me...)

Comment: @thaunknown54:  Please post your solution as an answer below and then "accept" your own answer.  This benefits the community and also gains you some rep points.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the problem can be fixed by taking a closer look at the wrong way of coding links `<a>`. In the script was forgotten (numerous times) to end the `<a>` tag with `</a>`. This script uses `<a>` to end the coding of a link.

Answer (score 0):

I hope IE9/any can be rendered as IE8 using

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/>
```

in the head of html